# Незащищённая (http://) страница содержит поля для ввода пароля?

Tags: javascript, безопасность

Такие ошибки выводятся.
Есть форма с type=password и через ajax 
пароль отправляется на сервер.

Firefox выводит ошибки:

> Незащищённая (http://) страница содержит поля
>   для ввода пароля. Это представляет собой угрозу безопасности, которая
>   позволяет украсть учетные данные для входа пользователя.
>
> Форма с незащищённым (http://) действием содержит поля для ввода
>   пароля. Это представляет собой угрозу безопасности, которая позволяет
>   украсть учетные данные для входа пользователя.

Пишут что прослушиванием трафика можно воровать пароли.

1. Как тогда безопасно передавать пароли по ajax?
2. Cookie передающиеся по ajax, тоже не зашифрованные, а значит если там хранить пароли, то это тоже не безопасно?

Comment: А что мешает постить ajax с https?

Comment: Хочется чтобы страница была http, там нажимаешь кнопку, выводится окно новое(где в dom был вставлен include type password), и потом на сервер можно было безопасно отправить пароль.
Делать iframe с https очень не хочется.

Comment: не, не прокатит. любая страница, где просят ввести пароль, в идеале, должна быть через SSL.

Comment: Раньше все работали по http :Р

Comment: И идеале, в 2016 году сайт должен работать по https полностью.) А последняя отмазка от его использования стала неактуальна месяц назад.

Comment: @andreymal а для тех, кто в танке - что случилось месяц назад?

Comment: @splash58 халявные сертификаты от Let's Encrypt всем и каждому (правда, без wildcard пока, но вроде должны будут появиться)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо. здорово. надо смотреть

Comment: @splash58 а как быть с локальными ресурсами, без внешнего доменного имени?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Атака Man In The Middle позволяет прослушивать трафик, внедряясь между клиентом и сервером. Таким образом любые конфиденциальные данные должны передаваться по защищённому каналу. 
В настоящее время он организуется посредством протокола HTTPS (HTTP + SSL). Поэтому самым простым способом для вас будет подключение SSL сертификата и использование HTTPS. Статей по теме более чем достаточно. Удачи :)

Answer (score 2):

Веб меняется. Чаще читай нововведения в новых релизах браузеров. Они хотят все сайты где есть ввод пароля на https:// Пока-что выводится предупреждение в консоль и серым цветом в адресной строке "Не защищено". В будущих версиях планируется выводить в адресной строке заметным цветом. Оранжевым или красным.

Правильно в комментарии написали, Let's Encrypt выдает всем сертификаты бесплатно.

Comment: это ели есть сайт и зарегистрировано его имя. для корпораивного использования достаточно IP, на него не получишь сертификат....

Answer (score -3):

Если уж вам так хочется сделать http, но для запроса - защитить, то используйте JSONP для запроса на сервер

Comment: И что это изменит?